# Python -- list index out of range -- on a simple SELECT statement?

Tags: python, sql

I'm new to Python, so maybe I'm making a newbie mistake.  But this doesn't seem the kind of error I should get in this circumstance.

On a very simple SELECT statement, I'm getting a "list index out of range" error.

```
  sql = """
        begin tran
        -- Several update statements are in this block.

        commit tran"""
    sql = sql.format(tablename=self.tablename, **self.mappings)
    #print(sql)
    self.cursor.execute(sql, (self.catalog_id,self.catalog_id,self.catalog_id,))


    self.cursor.execute("SELECT CaptionText, DisplayOrder FROM dbo.SizeOrder where CaptionText is not NULL and len(CaptionText)>0")  #This is the line that breaks!

    size_order = {row[0].lower(): row[1] for row in self.cursor}
```

It's the next to last row that breaks.  It's not doing any funny formatting.  I don't do any of the substitutions in this problem query. When run directly against the DB, it returns over 300 records.

The trace output definitely implicates that line of code.  I really suspected the next line b/c it involves indexes.  But a return after the execute helped nothing.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 782, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "import.py", line 167, in main
    db.transform_catalog((len(args)>4 and args[4] == "--skipimages") or (len(args)>5 and args[5] == "--skipimages") )
  File "import.py", line 235, in transform_catalog
    self.do_transform(skipImages)
  File "import.py", line 264, in do_transform
    self.insert_size_types()
  File "import.py", line 501, in insert_size_types
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT CaptionText, DisplayOrder FROM dbo.SizeOrder  where CaptionText is not NULL and len(Capt
ionText)>0")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1449, in execute
    self._free_stmt(SQL_CLOSE)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1971, in _free_stmt
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 986, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 951, in ctrl_err
    state = err_list[0][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What could I be doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a long shot but maybe it's related to a bug that is fixed in `pypyodbc 1.3.3`:  https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/issues/detail?id=42

Comment: it looks like you forgot to fetch the results of your query `results = self.cursor.fetchall()`

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bug. An unrelated error during some result processing in the library's internals, not input-related. [DeepSpace's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864360/python-list-index-out-of-range-on-a-simple-select-statement/31865193#comment51648070_31864360) is the likely cause.

Comment: So ... what is the solution?  Is there an upgrade or service pack or patch?

Comment: ?! ["...that is fixed in `pyodbc 1.3.3`"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864360/python-list-index-out-of-range-on-a-simple-select-statement/31865193?noredirect=1#comment51648070_31864360) wasn't clear enough?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: it's back in 1.3.4: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @user443854 file another question, that is definitely something else.